# Bone weight painting is linked to another bone

Tags: armature, weight-painting

[image: Weight paint of first bone]

[image: W|eight paint of second bone]

So as you can see from the two screenshots, both the bones have the exact same weight paint. They are somehow linked. In other words, if I update the weight paint of one of these two bones, it updates it for both. How can I unlink them?

EDIT:
[image: Bone weight issue]

As you can see on the far left the multipaint is not checked and checking the auto normalize does not seem to do anything either.
It also just seems to be this one specific bone (highlighted with a blue arrow) and it seems to always be linked to the bone I was working on before

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J26x1-2ROqum0nus15W_Fagv848jHuaD

Comment: Did you maybe activate the **MultiPaint** checkbox. Deactivate it, and check the **Auto Normalize** box.

Comment: Multipaint is not checked and checking auto normalize doesnt seem to make a difference. I have edited the post, please see for more info

Comment: You would have to press Auto Normalize, **before** editing the weights. [Upload your file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can help you more easily.

Comment: When I select the end joints in weight paint mode, the mesh turns purple indicating that there is no vertex group with the same name (assigned to it). You must create an associated vertex group. e.g. There is a **Wing Fourth Row 02.L.001** bone but no such vertex group...

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still relatively new to blender. I managed to learn something new now. I basically created another bone after I parented it to the mesh and therefore no vertex groups had been assigned to it. I have now created a vertex group and assigned it to the bone and it's working perfectly now.

Comment: Please don't add resolved in the questions title. I have added an answer, if you wish you can mark it as accepted by pressing the tick icon on the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigging geometry with armatures mainly depends on the armature modifier, vertex groups and the armature.

You can manually add the armature modifier to a mesh object and select an armature. The mesh object will deform based on it's vertex groups. ***Each bone of the armature (with the Deform checkbox checked) needs a vertex group with the same name.*** It will deform the vertices in that vertice group based on the weights in the group.

When parenting a mesh object to an armature you have the option for vertex groups to be created automatically. When you rename the armature bones, the vertex groups will be renamed as well. When you **rename vertex groups, armature bone names stay the same**: the links will be broken. When you add new bones, vertex groups will not be created automatically and the bones will influence nothing. Meaning if you want to add the deforming bone **bone_13.l** you have to create the vertex group *bone_13.l*. Then you can select the bone in weight paint mode and the associated vertex group will be selected as well, ready to be weight painted.